# Use LiveData with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

I tried to use `RecyclerView` with `LiveData` basically exactly as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585733/how-to-properly-use-livedata-with-recycleview) It's really on the beat what I am trying to do, and I imagine it is a quite normal use case. (There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489235/update-recyclerview-with-android-livedata) which aligns somewhat with mine )

**Goal:** Have an update in a table in a **RoomDB** propagate by `LiveData` to be visible as items in a `RecyclerView`.

I read up on [the paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) and it seems very good but say I do not need to divide into pages for performance. I do not quite understand everything, in that article

Here's some code from the article which I have a comment on which may be relevant to my question:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.user_list);
        UserAdapter<User> adapter = new UserAdapter();

        //Does the following line mean that they set the list on the adapter on each change in the underlying data?
        viewModel.usersList.observe(this, pagedList -> adapter.setList(pagedList));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

In the `observe` they just set the list for the adapter, in the current setup I have `notifyDataSetChanged()`(as in the linked question), which i realize is bad. I do not use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) which I guess is what I get for free in `PagedListAdapter` which appeals to me. I would not have arrived at just setting the list of the adapter in the `observe`, it seems to me that this is what makes `PagedListAdapter` do some heavy lifting.

If i don't want to take advantage of paging should I still use the paging components? (to get it to do DiffUtil things for me?)

How do I achieve the **Goal** as smoothly as possible with architecture components?

Edit: Also noticed paging component is in alpha at the moment

Comment: I am really waiting for proper answer for the problem but even one year later there is no real solution so only only solution is to use diffUtil and call notifyChange.

Comment: Any updates on this?